# TypeDescriptor.GetProperties from property in another class

Tags: c#

I am using GetProperties to get property file with reflection

```
PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType())[attrNane];
```

but is it possible to get `PropertyDescriptor` from another class?

example

```
class a {
 public string name;
}

class b {
 public b() {
  PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType())["a.name"];
 }
```

}

so I want to get `PropertyDescriptor`  from property name `"name"` in class `a`. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: `name` is not a property in this case, it's an internal field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`typeof` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) the get the `Type` of another class.

```
class a {
  public string name {get; set;}
}

class b {
  public b() {
    PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(a))["name"];
 }
```

Note that I changed `a.name` to a property.

Comment: Note that if you just have the type name in a string, but you know what assembly it comes from you will need to use Assembly.GetType, similarly if you know the assembly name as a string you will need to find the assembly in AppDomain.Current